# Atualizar o FullCalendar no onChange de um select

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Eu tenho um select html no header da minha page que lista algumas pessoas do banco de dados, quando alguma delas é escolhida, eu pego a ID dele e armazeno numa variável JS e envio essa variável por AJAX para o meu php, onde uso algumas **static functions** que requerem esse id da pessoa para buscar dados a respeito dela no banco, isso vem num array.

Eu pego esse array e meto um foreach passando o algumas informações da tabela para o evento no fullcalendar. Eu renderizo esses eventos na minha view 'list'. Na view 'month', eu renderizo o resultado de **outra function** que faz a mesma coisa que a primeira, mas o select vem de outra tabela.

Uso o viewRender para mudar a renderização dos arrays de eventos de acordo com a view selecionada, mas me ocorre que se eu mudar de uma pessoa para outra, os dados não são atualizados.

Já tentei remover os eventos, adicionar e re-renderizar, mas não foi.

A view 'month' permanece correta, mas a view list não muda se eu mudar a pessoa, ela continua sempre com os eventos referentes a primeira pessoa que foi selecionada.

Alguma ideia de como eu posso remover os eventos DE DOIS ARRAYS e re-renderizar quando eu mudar de pessoa no meu combo?

Answer (score 0):

Teria que remover os eventos e renderizar de novo.

**Exemplo:**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', data);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
```